# Adding a subtitle to a chart VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to insert text to act as a "subtitle" under my chart's actual title using VBA? I would like to reference the input in cell "N21" as my subtitle text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure how to handle it automatically, however, you can always "split" the main title using a CR or LF, and then change formatting on the 2nd art. (I just did so in a test, and first line at 18 size, the 2nd line at 10 .. )

Comment: I have tried an input box or using the And operator to add cell N21 to the title underneath it. nothing as worked so far

Comment: @Ditto:how did you do that exactly? I'm still fairly new to VBA as each step in my project presents me with another aspect of VBA I was unaware of. I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Ditto -- seems like this would make a good answer (with a little more detail added). I'll up-vote it if you do.

Comment: That would work perfectly but I'm not sure how to write that or what that means. Have 2 different size fonts would be perfect for this situation as well!

Comment: It's not a full answer, because I can't provide any hints as to how to do it in VBA .. just "manually" within Excel ... O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should help you out, although I'm not sure on changing the font size.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(2).Activate
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "new title" & Chr(10) & Range("C3").Value
End With
```

The Chr(10) is your carriage return for a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on an excellent suggestion by Ditto, here is a VBA sub which adds a subtitle to an existing chart with an existing title, along with a test routine showing how it is called.

```
Sub AddSubtitle(Ch As Chart, subtitle As String, Optional fontsize As Long = 12)
    Dim NewTitle As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim CT As ChartTitle

    Set CT = Ch.ChartTitle
    NewTitle = CT.Text
    NewTitle = NewTitle & Chr(13)
    i = 1 + Len(NewTitle)
    NewTitle = NewTitle & subtitle
    n = Len(subtitle)
    CT.Text = NewTitle
    CT.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, n).Font.Size = fontsize

End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    AddSubtitle myChart, "Subtitle", 10
End Sub
```